# Handling a vector of cv::Mat with a Method

Tags: opencv, pointers, vector, pass-by-reference

I want to give a method a vector to fill it with a different number of Mat Objects, something like this:

```
int main()
{
  vector<cv::Mat> areas;
  doSomething(areas);
  return 0;
}

doSomething(vector<cv::Mat> &areas)
{
  cv::Mat first = zeros(...
  cv::Mat second = ....
  cv::Mat third = ... 
  areas.push_back(first);
  areas.push_back(second);
  areas.push_back(third);
}
```

Of course that doesn't work, because there is not enough memory allocated at the begin and the memory is only on the stack!

A second idea I had is to make pointers:

```
int main()
{
  vector<cv::Mat> *areas = new vector<cv::Mat>();
  doSomething(&areas);
  return 0;
}

doSomething(vector<cv::Mat> *areas)
{
  cv::Mat first = zeros(...
  cv::Mat second = ....
  cv::Mat third = ... 
  areas->push_back(first);
  areas->push_back(second);
  areas->push_back(third);
}
```

But again the problem is, that I have no idea at the beginning how much space is to allocate.

The third idea was to return the vector at the "normal" way:

```
int main()
{
  vector<cv::Mat> areas;
  areas = doSomething();
  return 0;
}

vector<cv::Mat> doSomething()
{
  vector<cv::Mat> areas;
  cv::Mat first = zeros(...
  cv::Mat second = ....
  cv::Mat third = ... 
  areas->push_back(first);
  areas->push_back(second);
  areas->push_back(third);
  return areas;
}
```

In this case of course only the headers of the vector was copied and not the Mat Objects in the vector

Do you have any idea how i am able to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: do prefer the 1st version, there's nothing wrong with it. passing around pointers to cv::Mat is a bad idea (with respect to refcounting)

Comment: Your first try when you say "Of course that doesn't work, because there is not enough memory allocated at the begin and the memory is only on the stack!" - std::vector use dynamically allocated memory. You code looks ok. Why exactly do you say "that doesn't work"?

Comment: jep me too, but it didn't work! After calling the method the "areas" object has size 0, although in the method all the 3 Mat objects are added!

Comment: the fuuuuck! I made a second instance of the vector in the method, of course that can't work. But now my vector is filled with data and the Mat Objects in the vector are empty!

Comment: Hey, try this code: http://pastebin.com/Jtcr3e6Q. And tell me if it works for you. Also, tell me if this is what you want (sizes and stuff)

Comment: Thx all of you! @andrei it's nearly the same code as mine and it works as well as mine. The problem was another one, It depends on the rest of the code! The only failure was the double instance in the method

Comment: My guess would be that the `Mat`'s you pushed in got deallocated at the end of `doSomething` scope(I might be wrong though) and you are left with a vector that holds empty `Mat` headers.